# After hard restart can't connect to Postgresql (in Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, redis, foreman

My mac locked up so I had to do a hard shut down (hold down power key til it turns off, then turn it back on). Now when I try to launch my local rails app (which was running fine just before crash) I get the following Action Controller exception:

```
PG::ConnectionBad
could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the server 
running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket 
"/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I had a similar problem about a month ago when my computer crashed and I eventually found a solution. But I've been searching and researching for hours and no luck today.

I'm pretty much of a noob but for what it's worth, I'm starting the server with `foreman start` and using [Redis](https://redis.io/). But to be honest, I don't know exactly what those do.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you log into postgres from your command line?  Try typing psql in the command line to see if the database is running.  Foreman start is starting webrick and redis is just a blazing fast key/value store that holds everything in memory.  PG::Connection is telling you your postgres database is offline or your credentials/database.yml is wrong.

Comment: Do you have a `postmaster.pid` file somewhere? If so, remove that file and start PostgreSQL as normal. The presence of that file tells PostgreSQL that it is already running so it won't start again but a stray `postmaster.pid` file can get left around if PostgreSQL doesn't shut down properly.

Comment: @bkunzi01 `psql` yields: `-bash: psql: command not found`

Comment: @muistooshort I already removed `postmaster.pid` and I thought that would solve my problem. But apparently not.

Answer (score 2):

This usually works for me.

```
$ launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
$ pg_ctl restart -D /usr/local/var/postgres
$ launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

Comment: `launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist` yields: `/Users/robert/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist: No such file or directory`. When I look in finder, I see the file there. But it appears to be an alias (a generic file icon with an arrow) and when I double-click it I get "The operation can’t be completed because the original item for “homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist” can’t be found."

Comment: How did you install postgresql?

Comment: Well, I'm not completely sure. I thought it was just part of the rails bundle. I know I'm using homebrew for things. But I did just download and installed postgres.app as per another suggestion. I launched it and still get the same PG::ConnectionBad error when I do `foreman start`. FWIW when I run pg_ctl I get `-bash: pg_ctl: command not found`

Answer (score 2):

There is a file in the data directory of PostgreSQL that stores the process id of PostgreSQL server named:

> "postmaster.pid"

In case of a crash of the system, this file may still point to an old process or the file might be corrupted. The problem can be solved by deleting the file and starting PostgreSQL server.

In Mac the file is located in:

```
/usr/local/var/postgresql@[version of postgresql]
e.g. /usr/local/var/postgresql@9.6
```

Command summary for PostgreSQL version 9.6 in Mac:

```
cd /usr/local/var/postgresql@9.6$
mv  postmaster.pid postmaster.pid.bk
brew services start postgres@9.6
```

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately I ended up uninstalling and reinstalling postgresql:

`brew remove postgresql
brew install postgresql`

Maybe there was a less drastic solution, but it was pretty quick and painless and I'm back in business.

I'm working in a development environment and was prepared to lose my data and reseed my database, but all the data was still there.